# A self referential riddle?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Kinda self reference I guess
>
> but it seems logical
>
> I have decided my way, sticking to it
>
> it's the one that mostly expresses my spirit
>
> Whenever a soul center portal alignment connection is established
>
> any too intricate analysis is redundant
>
> Run the process of realization, whatever the outcome, of:
>
> Self reference again?
>
> And again?

<sub>*(First riddle, criticism greatly appreciated! (Even nonconstructive :) )

Also: I am not sure what tags to use.*</sub>

Hint:

> Music

Hint 2:

> k/4 religious leader

Hint 3: (the thread is getting old, this is a strong one):

> Singer initials: L.F.

Comment: Note to first-time riddlers: [The Riddle Sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/) can be helpful to those getting started in riddle-making (and determining tags).

Comment: Thanks for adding the knowledge tag, @GeorgeMenoutis! Don't underestimate the value of tags.

Comment: I don't underestimate them; I just am not enough time in here to know which ones are appropriate. Is there any place I can learn this? The tour has so little info...

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is:

> A fractal

Because

> they are following self-similar and infinitely repeating pattern. (Fits the 'Self reference' and 'I have decided my way, sticking to it it's the one that mostly expresses my spirit')

Also

> any too intricate analysis is redundant - as no mater how much you zoom in you see the same pattern again and again which also fits the self reference lines at the end

Comment: Not the thing I have in mind. Still, I love this site for the alternative answers. Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

The puzzle reads like

> Reworded song lyrics.

The general feeling I get from these lyrics is:

> Oasis - Don't Look Back in Anger

Though I can't map 1:1 the lines, so I'm sure this isn't right.

Comment: You are right about the first statement...but not for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Are you:

> Recursion?

Because of some key words in your verse:

> Recursion is a form of coding **logic** - a **process** - built upon **repeated self-reference**?

Also:

Whenever a soul center portal alignment connection is established any too intricate analysis is redundant

> I take to describe an infinite recursion loop leading to a cyclic redundancy error at run-time.

Comment: Not the intended answer.